# Phonegap jquery mobile link to external page and the DOM navigation

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova, hyperlink, external

When you use Phonegap and Jquery Mobile, you are required to identify external links with the full path such as 
'http://mywebsite.com/register.html'.  I assumed that even so, this page would still be added to the DOM as per the jquery mobile documentation

'By default, when you click on a link that points to an external page (ex. products.html), the framework will parse the link's href to formulate an Ajax request (Hijax) and displays the loading spinner.'

My problem is that when the register.html page is loaded (which happens to be a form), when I click on the submit button within that form, my jquery code to catch it never seems to fire.

```
$('#registerForm').live("submit", function() { 
alert("here ");
event.preventDefault();
 });
```

I have tried wrapping this within various events (on pageInit, pageshow, etc.) and it never seems to catch it.  It works in the browser fine.

I am not sure if the external page is in the DOM (I am not sure how to tell) , or if I am not using the proper 
event (pageshow, etc) to catch it.  Which would be the proper event?
I have no problem catching submits if the form is an internal page within the index.html.  Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Comment: external links are loaded in external browser or "inappbrowser"?

Comment: When not using phonegap this is not considered an external link.  Are you saying that with phonegap it is? and therefore need to handle it differently. How do you keep a consistent flow in your app if it pops out to an external browser everytime you link to a page loaded from your own server?

Answer (score 0):

you can add the `rel="external"` attribute to your link tag.

Adding this will make your `register.html` load scripts etc. as a normal page.

Now i cant really see your code on this, but if you havent tried it, i suggest you do so.

Oh.. One thing more.. `jQuery live()` is removed in the newer versions of jQuery

Comment: Forgot to say that my js is all in one js file referenced in index.html and have none in the register.html so I dont think rel=external will solve anything...but I will give it a try.  Yes thanks for the .live tip (I am aware of its deprecation but I am still using jquery 1.7 at the moment).